# ProgrammingError: (1064, ..) for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to query the RDS instance using the AWS lambda. I am coding it in python.

My insert query is :

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
 cur.execute("""insert into DocumentLanguagesInfo (documentId, version, language1, 
 language1Confidence, language2, language2Confidence, language3, language3Confidence, 
 otherLanguages) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (docId, version, lang1, 
 lang1Conf, lang2, lang2Conf, lang3, lang3Conf, otherLangs))
```

Where conn is the variable for connection to SQL server, which is established successfully.

But when I execute this query I get the error in the cloudwatch that:

```
[ERROR] ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/sqlConnection.py", line 100, in lambda_handler
    cur.execute("""insert into DocumentLanguagesInfo (documentId, version, language1, language1Confidence, language2, language2Confidence, language3, language3Confidence, otherLanguages) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (docId, version, lang1, lang1Conf, lang2, lang2Conf, lang3, lang3Conf, otherLangs))
```

I tried writing the code in this way but still it gives the same error:

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql_query = "insert into DocumentLanguagesInfo (documentId, version, language1, language1Confidence, language2, language2Confidence, language3, language3Confidence, otherLanguages) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        recordTuple = (docId, version, lang1, lang1Conf, lang2, lang2Conf, lang3, lang3Conf, otherLangs)

        cur.execute(sql_query, recordTuple)
        conn.commit()
```

What wrong am I doing in this query?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2) you can be reasonably confident that your schema design is flawed; a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? The error mentions `))`, but that doesn't appear in the query. The only place it appears is at the end of the call, after `otherLangs`, but that's Python code, not SQL.

Comment: You might get that error if the ending `"""` were after `otherLangs))`.

Comment: @Barmar, the code is copied correctly, and the syntax looks good, but still no idea why this error is coming.

Comment: @Barmar, I edited the question and tried one more way for implementing it, still doesn't works.

Comment: code seems OK - maybe you run different code. If you could generate string with SQL query and data then you could print it and copy to test directly in database using any database editor/viewer (ie. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) ) - and it may give more information about problem in query.

Comment: What is the value of `otherLangs`? What is the datatype of the `otherLanguages` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue might be in `otherLangs` being a list. Maybe using

```
recordTuple = (docId, version, lang1, lang1Conf, lang2, lang2Conf, lang3, lang3Conf, tuple(otherLangs))
```

will work better.

Comment: I don't think you can nest tuples in the `cursor.execute()` parameters.